# Research Proposal topic for Master's

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-proposal

I'm a Computer Science graduate and gonna apply for Masters this year. I was thinking about my research proposal (or rather a problem statement) to submit during the application process and I had a rather different problem in mind than the ones I see on internet. My topic is not based on a real life problem but rather about my musings of a fictional world (lets just say its an anime). So my question is, is it okay to submit a research proposal that doesn't address a real problem but rather entertains the musings of a nerdy fan, and how we can use machine learning / AI for that?

Comment: Is the problem of theoretical interest? Or is it only interesting because you like the anime?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I think it can be categorized as theoretical interest. I want to find an image or symbol based on a given text (its a spell). What I had in mind was that we do some tasks on the text and then predict the image/symbol. We can have a few images as a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it’s of theoretical interest, go for it. Maybe don’t tell everyone you meet that you want to do this because of the anime, but I also wouldn’t shy away from saying that it was inspired by something you saw on TV. Focus on the research problem first and the inspiration second and you’ll be fine.